# How to stop wifi from reenabling after being disabled

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, default

I have a machine that has a wired connection and a wifi card, running `Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit`.  I'd rather leave wifi unconnected all the time, but have the option of turning it back on whenever I want, which means leaving the network password saved, but disabling wifi.  At the moment, I can go to the network menu in the dock and uncheck `Enable Wifi`.

The problem is that after restarting, and sometimes just after the computer has been on for a while, that option simply re-enables itself and I get a wifi connection message.

- How do I get that option to persist?
- Why does it switch back to its default all the time?

I did have a script that force restarted networking on wake to get rid of another issue.  I've commented that out so it doesn't do anything anymore, but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bios option: in my laptop I can flag my wifi card as "last-status" instead of enable/disable. That's only if you want to disable the wifi card.

Otherwise it's enough to disable the flag `automatic connection` by Network Manager on your wifi connection SSID.

Comment: Oh, man, I feel a bit dumb now.  I totally missed that option in the network settings.  I've unchecked it for now, and I imagine that should work.  I will however also investigate the BIOS issue and report back when I get a chance to.

Comment: that's happen. But now I know that's possible communicate to Network Manager via cli, that I didn't mind, so for me yours was an useful question :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished easily using `nmcli`.

Add the following line into `/etc/rc.local` prior to the `exit 0` line:

```
nmcli nm wifi off
```

You can arbitrarily re-enable the wifi either through the network manager dropdown menu like you have been turning it off or by running the following command from cli:

```
nmcli nm wifi on
```

Commands placed in /etc/rc.local are ran automatically as root whenever your system boots up.

For more information on `nmcli` and its capabilities, simply run view the man page for it with `man nmcli`.

Comment: Thanks, I would however like to avoid using commands.  I'd like a system that simply respects the convenient menu toggle that I'm currently using, rather than requiring the editing of a script.  I'd upvote you, but I can't.  gio900 provided a better answer for my situation.